# Python requests.get return error json.decoder.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, jsondecoder

I am trying to read bulk data from server of which I have no control over.

Error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 1794)
```

[Error Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrZa8.png)

This `.json()` call throws error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError json.decoder`.

```
import requests
Data = requests.get(Data_Url ,headers=session["headers"]).json()
print(Data)
```

This `.text` returns data in a string which I can't manipulate.

```
import requests
Data = requests.get(Data_Url ,headers=session["headers"]).text
print(Data)
```

As shown below the format of data seems to be

```
{}
{}
{}
```

**How can manipulate `request.get` response so that I have JSON format and separated by `{},{}`?**

```
{ "Data" : [{},{}]}
```

```
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"cg3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"3g3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"pg3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"GA3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"zQ3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"qQ3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"Fw3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"Nw3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"hw3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"DSQ3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
```

Comment: Looks like JSONL format...

Comment: if it's not actually json, and you have no control over it, then don't try to parse it as json. Figure out what it is and read that. It doesn't even close the brackets?

Comment: The format is **not** [JSONL](https://jsonlines.org/), nor is it valid [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (as already noted) — which make "fixing" things a little trickier…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results you're getting from `.text` aren't in a valid JSON (or Python literal) format. After studying the results, I determined that each line in the string returned is missing the characters "`}]}]}`" at the end that would correct that problem.

The code below adds them to each line, and then parses/evaluated it using the [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function to turn it into a Python dictionary. A [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is then utilized to put them into a list. In other words, you don't have to bother nesting them inside a dictionary like the `{"Data": [{}, {}, ...]}` you proposed (unless you *really* want to for some unknown reason).

```
from ast import literal_eval
import json
from pprint import pprint

requests_get_text = """\
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"cg3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"3g3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"pg3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"GA3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"zQ3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"qQ3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"Fw3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"Nw3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"hw3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
{"resourceType":"Person","id":"DSQ3","extension":[{"extension":[{"valueCoding":{"system":"http://terminology.hl7.org/","code":"UNK","display":"Unknown"}
"""

# Convert result from requests.get().text into valid JSON/Python format.
data = [literal_eval(f'{line}' '}]}]}\n')
                    for line in requests_get_text.splitlines()]
pprint(data, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
[{'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': 'cg3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]},
 {'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': '3g3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]},
 {'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': 'pg3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]},
 {'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': 'GA3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]},
 {'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': 'zQ3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]},
 {'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': 'qQ3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]},
 {'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': 'Fw3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]},
 {'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': 'Nw3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]},
 {'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': 'hw3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]},
 {'resourceType': 'Person',
  'id': 'DSQ3',
  'extension': [{'extension': [{'valueCoding': {'system': 'http://terminology.hl7.org/',
                                                'code': 'UNK',
                                                'display': 'Unknown'}}]}]}]
```

Comment: I'm glad to hear that...you're welcome. Note that the *real* problem is that the producer of the data isn't doing it correctly — so this is just a workaround.